# npm fail to install node-hid (faild to install last version of Nodejs)

Tags: node.js, npm, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to install node-hid on my Raspberry Pi (Raspbian).
But node-hid need a high version of Nodejs to work ( >= 0.8 ) and my version is only 0.6.19.

So, I've tried to install Nodejs v0.10.26 with nvm... Nvm installed successfully nodejs v0.10.26, but npm still use the old version of Nodejs. How can the v0.10.26 version of Nodejs be used in the entire system ? And how can I install node-hid ?

Thank you for your help

Here is the code I get when i'm trying to install node-hid :

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo npm install -g node-hid
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/node-hid

npm ERR! Error: failed to fetch from registry: node-hid
npm ERR!     at /usr/share/npm/lib/utils/npm-registry-client/get.js:139:12
npm ERR!     at cb (/usr/share/npm/lib/utils/npm-registry-client/request.js:31:9)
npm ERR!     at Request._callback (/usr/share/npm/lib/utils/npm-registry-client/request.js:136:18)
npm ERR!     at Request.callback (/usr/lib/nodejs/request/main.js:119:22)
npm ERR!     at Request.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/nodejs/request/main.js:212:58)
npm ERR!     at Request.emit (events.js:88:20)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/nodejs/request/main.js:209:10)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:67:17)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.onError (/usr/lib/nodejs/request/tunnel.js:164:21)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.g (events.js:156:14)
npm ERR! You may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://bugs.debian.org/npm>
npm ERR! or use
npm ERR!     reportbug --attach /home/pi/npm-debug.log npm
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! System Linux 3.6.11+
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "node-hid"
npm ERR! cwd /home/pi
npm ERR! node -v v0.6.19
npm ERR! npm -v 1.1.4
npm ERR! message failed to fetch from registry: node-hid
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/pi/npm-debug.log
npm not ok
```

And in npm-debug.log :

```
info it worked if it ends with ok
verbose cli [ '/usr/bin/nodejs', '/usr/bin/npm', 'install', 'node-hid', '-g' ]
info using npm@1.1.4
info using node@v0.6.19
verbose config file /root/.npmrc
verbose config file /usr/etc/npmrc
verbose config file /usr/share/npm/npmrc
silly exec /usr/bin/nodejs "/usr/share/npm/bin/npm-get-uid-gid.js" "nobody" 1000
silly spawning [ '/usr/bin/nodejs',
silly spawning   [ '/usr/share/npm/bin/npm-get-uid-gid.js', 'nobody', 1000 ],
silly spawning   null ]
silly output from getuid/gid {"uid":65534,"gid":1000}
silly output from getuid/gid 
verbose cache add [ 'node-hid', null ]
silly cache add: name, spec, args [ undefined, 'node-hid', [ 'node-hid', null ] ]
verbose parsed url { pathname: 'node-hid', path: 'node-hid', href: 'node-hid' }
verbose addNamed [ 'node-hid', '' ]
verbose addNamed [ null, '' ]
silly name, range, hasData [ 'node-hid', '', false ]
verbose raw, before any munging node-hid
verbose url resolving [ 'https://registry.npmjs.org/', './node-hid' ]
verbose url resolved https://registry.npmjs.org/node-hid
http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/node-hid
ERR! Error: failed to fetch from registry: node-hid
ERR!     at /usr/share/npm/lib/utils/npm-registry-client/get.js:139:12
ERR!     at cb (/usr/share/npm/lib/utils/npm-registry-client/request.js:31:9)
ERR!     at Request._callback (/usr/share/npm/lib/utils/npm-registry-client/request.js:136:18)
ERR!     at Request.callback (/usr/lib/nodejs/request/main.js:119:22)
ERR!     at Request.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/nodejs/request/main.js:212:58)
ERR!     at Request.emit (events.js:88:20)
ERR!     at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/nodejs/request/main.js:209:10)
ERR!     at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:67:17)
ERR!     at ClientRequest.onError (/usr/lib/nodejs/request/tunnel.js:164:21)
ERR!     at ClientRequest.g (events.js:156:14)
ERR! You may report this log at:
ERR!     <http://bugs.debian.org/npm>
ERR! or use
ERR!     reportbug --attach /home/pi/npm-debug.log npm
ERR! 
ERR! System Linux 3.10.25+
ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "node-hid" "-g"
ERR! cwd /home/pi
ERR! node -v v0.6.19
ERR! npm -v 1.1.4
ERR! message failed to fetch from registry: node-hid
verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: What is in `/home/pi/npm-debug.log` ?

Comment: are you connected to internet? do you receive the same error after multiple attempts?

Comment: Yes I'm connected to the internet.. I've tried many times, and it still doesn't work !

Answer (score 5):

### The following worked for me:

#### Check your system is up to date:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

#### Install latest version of node

```
sudo wget http://node-arm.herokuapp.com/node_latest_armhf.deb
sudo dpkg -i node_latest_armhf.deb
```

#### Check latest version of node is installed

```
node -v
```

#### Install dependancies for node-hid

Not entirely sure if it is all needed (some will likely already be installed) but is the only thing that has worked for me..

```
sudo apt-get install g++ curl
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev apache2-utils
sudo apt-get install build-essential
sudo apt-get install pkg-config

sudo npm install node-gyp -g

sudo apt-get install git-core
sudo apt-get install libudev-dev
sudo apt-get install libusb-1.0-0-dev
```

#### Install node-hid

```
npm install node-hid
```

---

**Note:** The node install above is only for Raspbian, if you would like to experiment in Ubuntu use the following code to install node instead, everything else stays the same:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:chris-lea/node.js  
sudo apt-get update  
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```